# Slice a vector with a specified step in DolphinDB

Tags: python, slice, dolphindb

I have a DATE vector shown as follows:

[image]

I want to obtain data once every 5 days, like this:

[image]

I can do this with the following srcipt in python:

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 23, 13, 14, 15]
print(A[0::5])
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Any similar method in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: Calculate the index of elements you want to fetch.

```
dataVector = 2021.01.01..2021.02.28
dataVector[at(0..(size(dataVector)-1)%5==0)]
```

Method 2: Use `cutPoints` function. But the last value obtained needs to be deleted because the upper bound is inclusive.

```
cutPoints(dataVector, ceil(dataVector.size()\5))
```

Method 3: Set a columnar tuple and slice it with function `cut`, which is only supported by the version 2.00.9.

```
cut(v, 5).setColumnarTuple!()[0]
```